# nor for that matter

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the sentence "He had not uttered  a sound while the punishment was administered but then, nor for that matter, had I." How am I to understand "but then, nor for that matter, had I"?

Comment: The comma's in the wrong place. It should be *"but then nor, for that matter, had I"*. This is an understandable mistake, because the original sentence really wants a comma on both sides of *"nor"*. But if you put both commas in, the result looks horrible, so you need to use just the more important one.

Comment: @Peter: Per my answer, I think the problem with comma placement there is basically down to the fact that two distinct idiomatic usages are being strung together, and are "sharing" the word ***nor***. I think there should *always* be a comma before ***but***, but that's by-the-by. If you had *either* (not *both*) of the two "problematic" usages, you wouldn't need another comma at all. But when they're *both* present, how do you decide which one gets "custody" of the word ***nor**?*

Comment: It means he did not utter a sound and neither did I.

Answer (score 6):

I think OP's example is *not* very well-formed.

In a nutshell, the problem is ***but then nor*** and ***but nor for that matter*** both mean effectively the same thing. It doesn't really work for me when ***nor*** is being used by both constructions at once.

Having said that, the intended *meaning* is clear enough. Simplifying,...

> 1: He didn't go, but then nor did I
>    2: He didn't go, but nor for that matter did I
>    3: ?He didn't go, but then nor for that matter did I

...all mean there's nothing particularly surprising about the fact that he didn't go (I didn't go either, so it's not like he did something really unusual that no-one else would do).

Comment: Additionally commentary aside, ;-), I don't agree with what you conclude the OP's example means.  I think the whole "...nor did I..." bit simply means "neither did I (utter a sound).

Comment: @Kristina: Do you mean that so far as you're concerned, the meaning isn't affected at all by either (or *both!*) of ***then*** and ***for that matter**?* Admittedly, using the conjunction ***but*** instead of starting a new sentence implies *some* relationship between what he did and what I did, but you seem to be ignoring even that.

Comment: At its most basic essence, yes, that's what I'm saying. I'm sure there's nuance in that statement as to why it's significant that neither uttered a sound but the gist of it is that all the "noise" boils down to the fact that neither uttered a sound.  We have no further context to conjecture why that's significant.

Comment: @Kristina: I think you're completely mistaken. To my mind, there's no question but that ***then*** and ***for that matter*** both "mitigate" the preceding statement, implying that the speaker and/or audience might have been somewhat surprised by the first statement *unless and until* the second statement is added and introduced by either or both of those expressions.

Comment: That could be - but then ambiguity will cause that. :-)

Comment: I am still curious if punishment was administered to both, or if the author was but an onlooker. That is yet another ambiguity here.

Comment: It could be that the sound the onlooker failed to make was a protest rather than a cry of pain.

Comment: Just to satisfy your curiosity the punishment was administered on both. If this helps...

Comment: @Reg, Kristina: Why *another* ambiguity? I don't see any ambiguity beyond what's inevitable with *any* utterance devoid of its original context. If you were *reading* the book, like OP, you'd obviously know if the narrator was also being punished or simply an onlooker. Or indeed, noting the Past Perfect, if the narrator had silently endured the same punishment on some earlier occasion, and was now a silent spectator. It's stretching the meaning of *ambiguous* if all you mean is we don't know exactly *why* they were both silent. Maybe that's also contextual. But if not, it's hardly ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the question is about meaning more than punctuation.  If so...the sentence says

1. He had not uttered a sound while the punishment was administered.
2. I  had not uttered a sound while the punishment was administered.

Comment: It would be more clear if the author had moved the "aside" clauses `then` and `for that matter` together instead of splitting the second thought, i.e. `but then, for that matter, nor had I`